# Issues using ivy:publish task

Tags: ivy

I'm trying to use **ivy:publish** to publish a jar that I've built to the .ivy repository, but I'm getting an error. I'm pretty sure I'm not using it correctly, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

The project structure is something like this:

```
root--|
      |--src
      |--build
      |      |
      |      |--someorganisation-commonlib-1.0.0.jar
      |
      |--ivy.xml
      |--build.xml
```

The build.xml looks something like this:

```
<target name="publish"> 
        <ivy-publish organisation="someorganisation" resolver="local" module="commonlib" revision="1.0.0">
               <artifacts pattern="build/[organisation]-[module](-[revision])(-[type]).[ext]" />
        </ivy-publish>  
    </target>
```

ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

        <info
            organisation="someorganisation"
            module="commonlib"
            status="integration">
        </info>

    <dependencies>  
            <dependency org="com.thoughtworks.xstream" name="xstream" rev="1.3.1" transitive="false"/>
            <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.1" transitive="false"/>
            <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-jdk14" rev="1.6.1" transitive="false"/>
            <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="1.6.2" transitive="false"/>
        </dependencies>

    </ivy-module>
```

When I run the build.xml, I get the following error:

```
 C:\workspaces\wkspc\someproject\build.xml:8: someorganization#commonlib;1.0.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ivy file not found in cache for someorganization#commonlib;1.0.0: please resolve dependencies before delivering (C:\Documents and Settings\someuser\.ivy2\cache\resolved-someorganization-commonlib-1.0.0.xml)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've forgotten a [publications](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/publications.html) section in your ivy file.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="someorganisation" module="commonlib"/>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="commonlib" type="jar"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency org="com.thoughtworks.xstream" name="xstream" rev="1.3.1" transitive="false"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.1" transitive="false"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-jdk14" rev="1.6.1" transitive="false"/>
        <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="1.6.2" transitive="false"/>
    </dependencies>    
</ivy-module>
```

The *status* and *revision* (pubrevision) fields can be specified by the [publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html) task as follows:

```
   <ivy:publish resolver="${publish.resolver}" pubrevision="${publish.revision}" status="${publish.status}">
        <artifacts pattern="${build.dir}/[organisation]-[artifact].[ext]"/>
    </ivy:publish>
```

**Note 1:**

It would be simpler to generate the jar file without the revision number in the name. Just let ivy's artifact pattern pick up the jar file.

**Note 2:**

You will require an ivy resolve at some stage in your build, otherwise the ivy file doesn't get processed.