# How to add custom jar in Apache Ivy

Tags: apache, maven, ant, ivy

Our application has a custom jar trades.jar and I want to upload it to local Apache Ivy repository. How should I do it.

I know in maven it can be done using command 'mvn deploy:deploy'

Answer (score 3):

For an ivy publish example see:

- [Issues using ivy:publish task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304562/issues-using-ivypublish-task/8317109#8317109)

And if you want use a command-line solution:

- [good ivy tutorial for local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200762/good-ivy-tutorial-for-local-repository/2279596#2279596)

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar with ant/ivy, you are looking for [ivy:publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/publish.html)