# archiva graphic interface doesn't find my artifact

Tags: java, maven, ivy, artifacts, archiva

I have this problem, i have tried to publish an artifact of mine in my archiva repository, but even if phisical it seems that everything is ok when i go to the ui view of archiva i don't find anything about that artifact.
I have allready try to do the scan of the repositories, but nothing happens, i had look into the log file, and the only error that i see is this one

> Not a valid artifact path in a Maven 2 repository, filename 'bbi-resutil.jar' doesn't start with artifact ID 'resutil'

i suspect that the error is in my make pom structure

## Build.xml

```
<ivy:makepom ivyfile="ivy.xml" pomfile="bbi-resutil-pom.pom" conf="default,runtime">
    <mapping conf="default" scope="compile"/>
    <mapping conf="runtime" scope="runtime"/>
</ivy:makepom>
```

## ivy.xml

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="bbi-resutil" type="pom" ext="pom"/>
    <artifact name="bbi-resutil" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
</publications>
```

i don't really understand if it is necessaire that something else must be in the ivy.xml, or if th problem is something else,
If it's the problem how i have to structure the making of the pom?

Comment: Which version of Archiva do you use? Best would be to ask on the mailing lists...

Comment: Why do you think it's the POM structure? The error message would appear to indicate a problem with the ivy module name. Is it "resutil" instead of bbi-resutil?